# How to use transition for background image slide show without fading the contents?

Tags: jquery, slideshow, css-transitions

I want to use css transition for background image slide show, using jQuery. 
Is it possible to do so without fading the contents in the div ? 
If so, How ? Please help.
Here is my code without transition so far:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
var images = ['images/slide1.jpg','images/slide3.jpg','images/slide4.jpg','images/slide5.jpg','images/slide7.jpg',];
var i = 0;
var timeoutVar;

function changeBackground() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutVar); // just to be sure it will run only once at a time

    jQuery('#page').css('background-image', function() {
        if (i >= images.length) {
            i=0;
        }
        return 'url(' + images[i++] + ')';      
    });

    // call the setTimeout every time to repeat the function
    timeoutVar = setTimeout(changeBackground, 5000);
}

// Call it on the first time and it will repeat
changeBackground();        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible; You have to use the CSS `transition` property.

Just add this CSS:

```
#page {
    transition: background-image .7s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: background-image .7s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: background-image .7s ease-in-out; 
   -o-transition: background-image .7s ease-in-out; 
}
```

Everytime the `background-image` property of the `#page` div is changed, it will trigger an animation with 0.7 seconds duration (you can also change that value to fit your necessities).

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uYK8f/2/).

**EDIT:** This only works in webkit-based browsers. I'll edit this if I'll find a cross-browser solution.

Comment: Thanks, but oddly it just works on my chrome. And not firefox and IE. Maybe something wrong with my pc ?

Comment: Nope; I checked and it doesn't work in my Moz and IE, too. I've just read here ( http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animation-of-property-types- ) that the background-image property is not animatable, and it may be the issue. Sorry about that! I'll try to find out if there's another way to achieve the result.